# Source code for disc view in music player in android 2.2

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

Hey I want to make my own music player and I want to show the list of songs in disc view as shown [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1188757) which is available in all android phone's music player. So where can I found code for that. I heard that all this source code is freely available. I tried hard to find it but couldn't get it.

Thanking you in advance. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: See this link: http://www.mediafire.com/file/k766kgby3a51pk9/MyMediaPlayer.zip

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. And I found: [Vanilla Music Player for Android ](https://github.com/kreed/vanilla) [also This] (https://github.com/fabrantes/rockonnggl) and [This](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Music).